# $obj1->obj2()['something'];works only on localhost

Tags: php

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php echo $Main->GetInfo()['Players'] . '/' . $Main->GetInfo()['MaxPlayers']; ?>
```

On Localhost, this works perfectly. When I upload it to a web server though, I get this message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/www/.../header.php on line 111
```

Why does this happen? I can not change `GetInfo()` to `$GetInfo` as it'll return undefined.

Comment: What versions of PHP on localhost and the server are you running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In localhost you're using PHP 5.4, in your server the version is 5.3 or less, so you can't use that syntax.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

In PHP 5.3 you should use:

```
<?php
$info = $Main->GetInfo();
echo $info['Players'] . '/' . $info['MaxPlayers'];
?>
```

Comment: Indeed. Specifically, from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): "As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable."